# How to manage a long array unique to each user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose as my ODM and I have some trouble achieving what I want.

I have a User collection, and each of my user should have a "list" which would be the same for everyone, for example :

```
{ egg: false,
water: false,
wine: false }
```

And for each entry of this list, users could set true or false, whether they have the entry or not.

The definitive list should have about 1000 entries which. (the entry are all the same for the users, only the value (true/false) changes)

As it is a really big number, I don't know how to manage this.

I thought of some solution, but each of them doesn't seem to be really efficient :

- adding a "list" array within my UserSchema, containing the name of each entry and the value the user would have set. (that would be quite big)
- create a ListSchema in which I would set all entries' name, and then link it to each user, but I don't see how the values could be unique to the user...

If anyone knows how to do this, I would be very thankful!

Comment: If the number of 'true' entries is small you could store a copy of the list entries for that user in a single document per user whilst maintaining a separate collection for all items. If you want to be more relational - use a relational database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the main goal of the website for the user is to try to get all entries, and so, to get everything to 'true', so there won't be a small number of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can move all available `entries` into a separate collection and use `One-to-Many` relation to the Users' collection. Check out [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) page for more information about document references in MongoDB.